# How to plot the coordinates of a point on a sphere using a parametric formula?

Tags: matrices, 3d, parametric, spherical-coordinates, spheres

I am trying to **plot the coordinates of red point `A`** in the graphic below, which is the intersection of the red curve `F1` and the outer purple circle `A0`. The software I am using (GeoGebra) allows me to create intersections, but the numerical method the software uses is a little flaky, resulting in occasional errors. Plus, the intersections often disappear if I rotate the sphere when they shouldn't. Therefore I would like to plot the coordinates **using parametric formulas** instead.

[image]

Here are some facts:

- The radius of the sphere is 1 unit.
- The 2D angle between point `A` and point `PointBottom` around point `PointCenter` on the screen should be close to `16.1021140390572°` or thereabouts. (I can't count on this value being entirely accurate due to the numerical issues I mentioned above.)
- There are twelve green longitudinal arcs, so there is a 30° angle separating each of them around the vertical axis in 3D space.

I am using the following rotation matrix to draw the curves and plot other points:

```
a11 = cos(sphyaw1) cos(sphyaw2) - cos(sphpitch) sin(sphyaw1) sin(sphyaw2)
a12 = sin(sphpitch) sin(sphyaw2)
a13 = cos(sphyaw2) sin(sphyaw1) + cos(sphyaw1) cos(sphpitch) sin(sphyaw2)
a21 = sin(sphyaw1) sin(sphpitch)
a22 = cos(sphpitch)
a23 = -cos(sphyaw1) sin(sphpitch)
```

For instance, the parametric formula for the red curve `F1` is:

```
x = cos(30°) sin(phi) a11 + cos(phi) a12 + sin(30°) sin(phi) a13
y = cos(30°) sin(phi) a21 + cos(phi) a22 + sin(30°) sin(phi) a23
```

where `phi` is between 0° and 180°.

The values for the other parameters are:

```
sphyaw1 = 330° (angle around the vertical axis)
sphpitch = 30° (angle around the horizontal axis)
sphyaw2 = 0° (angle around the vertical axis a second time)
```

These affect the orientation of the whole sphere. They are also supposed to be variable.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: It may help to clarify what specifically is stumping you. After reading your question I am not sure where exactly you need help. Overall it is a good question.

Comment: I want to know how to plot the Point A using a formula. In the software I am currently using I have created intersections using the point-and-click mouse, but such intersections are sort of glitchy and undesirable for other reasons specific to that program.